# Wordpress не отрабатывает произвольный php код в теле страницы

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Вывожу список последних статей на главной странице wordpress используется elementor для визуального редактирования, и виджет произвольной вставки php кода
Код работает и выводит последние посты если я авторизован как админ, если смотреть с режима инкогнито код не отрабатывает и выводится на форнт часть кода текстом:
Результат в режиме инкогнито:

[image: Результат в режиме инкогнито:]

Почему код может не отрабатывать?

```
<div class="last_news_home_head"><h2>Новости экономики и финансов</h2></div>
    <div>
    <?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' ); ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="home_page_last_post" >
    <div class="widget-home-news-img">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="home_page_last_post_content"> 
    <li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <div class="home_page_last_post_df" >
    <?php echo get_the_date('j F Y в H:i'); ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="home_page_last_post_prevtxt" > <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php the_tags( ' ', '  '); ?>
    </li>
    <div class="home_blog_b_news_previevs_content_btn">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Узнать больше</a>                                                    
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Твой елементор или какой-то плагин "оптимизации" или "безопасности" ломает код.

Answer (score 0):

В WordPress запрещено вставлять произвольный php-код в записи, есть способ выключить эту защиту, но это огромная дыра в безопасности, оно вам надо? Но есть другой более безопасный метод путём создания плагина и шорткода. Можно прочитать про создание шорткода [здесь](https://wpschool.ru/create-shortcode/).

Вот пример простого шорткода:

```
function text_shortcode() {
    return 'Привет, мир!';
}
add_shortcode('textshortcode', 'text_shortcode');
```

Если вы вставите [textshortcode] в запись, то увидите: Привет, мир! По аналогии, вы можете поступить со своей проблемой.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)